# C++ unordered_map exception safety

Tags: c++11, unordered-map, exception-safety

I was wandering the C++ specifications (cplusplus.com) and found that there's nothing told about exception safety for std::unordered_map

so basically if I write

```
map["foo"]=5;
```

and an exception is thrown because I'm out of memory or bad_alloc, what can I assume about my map?

- It is left in a valid state? (basic guarantee)
- It is left unchanged? (strong guarantee)
- It is left in unvalid state ? (no guarantee)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

23.2.4.1  Exception safety guarantees [associative.reqmts.except]

> 2 For associative containers, if an exception is thrown by any
>   operation from within an insert or emplace function inserting a single
>   element, the insertion has no eftect.

This paragraph applies to the indexing operator.  So:

- It is left unchanged. (strong guarantee)

Comment: thanks! I was suspecting that was the strong guarantee but couldn't find any documentation.